# Images from Asset catalogs not loading on physical iPhone 5 but do show up on 6S and simulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

My app is loading images from an asset catalog.

I created the catalog by dragging and dropping in the Visual Studio editor.

When I load the app on a physical iPhone 6S, the simulator as a iPhone 6S or the simulator as a iPhone 5, the images display correctly.

When I load the app on a physical iPhone 5 none of them display.

In my project structure, all the images follow the same format:

`Resources/Media.xcassets/Image1.imageset/image_1.png
 Resources/Media.xcassets/Image1.imageset/image_1@2x.png
 Resources/Media.xcassets/Image1.imageset/image_1@3x.png`

and `Resources/Media.xcassets/Image1.imageset/Contents.json` is:

```
{
  "images": [
    {
      "scale": "1x",
      "idiom": "universal",
      "filename": "image_1.png"
    },
    {
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "universal",
      "filename": image_1@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "scale": "3x",
      "idiom": "universal",
      "filename": "image_1@3x.png"
    }
  ],
  "properties": {},
  "info": {
    "version": 1,
    "author": ""
  }
}
```

I am loading them using `UIImage.FromBundle("Image1");`. The value is fine on the physical 6S and the simulator 5 but null on the physical 5.

I tried the deprecated method of adding `image_test.png`, `image_test@2x.png` and `image_test@3x.png` loosely in the Resources/ folder and these load fine on all platforms.

Any advice on where I'm going wrong? I'm confused because both of my devices should be using the same `@2x` images. I've deleted `bin/iPhone/`, cleaned and rebuilt numerous times with no luck.

Comment: Have you already uninstalled the app on the issue device and re-side-loaded the app?

Comment: I haven't, I've been letting Xamarin deal with overwriting the app. I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: Sure thing, added it as an answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling the application from the device completely. I find with sideloading, when you add or change images, this needs to be done along with possibly clearing the `/bin/` and `/obj/` folders and rebuilding the app, as you said you already did.

Most other times, this should not be necessary.